# How to create tab headers with arrows and dots in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I am creating tabitem dynamically in WPF. I need to create the tab headers with arrows that shows a set of tab headers on arrow click like the below image.

[image]

For eg. If i have 10 tabs , 3 tabs should be shown initially then on clicking the next button, the next 3 tabs should be shown.

I found the tabpanel in the tab header template useful that displays the elements on multiple rows on more or less equal count in each row.

The code for the control template of the tab control as follows

```
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid  Grid.Column="0" Background="#f7f7f7">
                                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel"  IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Border x:Name="contentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                                <Grid>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
```

Now i get the output as

[image]

How to show this multiple rows into a single row with arrows to move to the next row. Any code samples will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the TabPanel Template, since that's where the multi-row layout is created?

Comment: @grek40 I tried to create a copy of the template using the blend by Edit Style -> Edit a Copy . but the option is disabled. I can only create Edit Style -> Create Empty. Is there any other way to have a look at the tabpanel template?

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are right. You will probably have to replace the TabPanel by a custom itemspanel within the TabControl template.

Comment: @grek40 Okay i will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you need is a custom scroll-view that wraps a custom itemspanel for the tab headers.

The following scrollviewer template places the scrollbar for horizontal scrolling left from the items instead of below - this effectively reduces it to the two scroll buttons. Also note, the `PART_VerticalScrollBar` is permanently collapsed in this template.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now, within the TabControl Template, you can replace the `TabPanel` by a horizontal `StackPanel`, wrapped in a `ScrollViewer` with above custom template:

```
...
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
</ScrollViewer>
...
```

This should roughly produce the desired UI and its a starting point to configure the desired behavior (like, how much do you scroll left and right with each click on the scroll arrows, ...)